# tor browser stuck on establishing an encrypted directory connection

Tags: encryption

i'm trying to connect to `tor` browser with all my might with my college PC to get some E-books but it's stuck at `tor browser stuck on establishing an encrypted directory connection` i've tried to use meek but no help , here are the messages i'm getting.

```
4/11/2017 15:43:10 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/11/2017 15:43:10 PM.800 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "bridges" (was using "default") 
4/11/2017 15:44:34 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/11/2017 15:44:34 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/11/2017 15:44:34 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/11/2017 15:44:34 PM.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/11/2017 15:44:41 PM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
4/11/2017 15:44:41 PM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
4/11/2017 15:45:02 PM.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.9:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/11/2017 15:45:02 PM.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.99.11.54:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/11/2017 15:45:02 PM.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/11/2017 15:45:02 PM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:15937 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/11/2017 15:45:02 PM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/11/2017 15:45:02 PM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/11/2017 15:45:02 PM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 85.17.30.79:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/11/2017 15:45:02 PM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.13:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/11/2017 15:45:02 PM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/11/2017 15:45:02 PM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/11/2017 15:45:02 PM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/11/2017 15:45:02 PM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.95.36.142:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/11/2017 15:48:38 PM.000 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/11/2017 15:48:38 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/11/2017 15:48:38 PM.000 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Comment: It looks like the default `obfs4` bridges are blocked, you could try fetching some fresh ones from https://bridges.torproject.org/ or use one of the `meek` variants.